# How to reset Singleton object - .Net core DI - Deployed on Azure Service Fabric with multiple nodes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

We have a .net core API, where we are using one singleton object to store some information. We registered that object as singleton (Dependency Injection) in configure method of pipeline.

Now We have a requirement where we need to reset that object (null or blank) and set it again in next request for that API. But as the application runs on Service fabric on multiple instances/nodes, How can we reset the singleton object of all the instances?

Answer (score 0):

Then don't use a singleton. Register it as scoped, since that's the lifetime you now need. Also, even as a singleton, you still have an instance per app instance/node. There is no such thing as share objects between app instances.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. We need a singleton object that keeps some data related to multiple tenants. But if someone has changed that value from back end then we need to invalidate that value and get the new one. I understand that there is no such thing which we can share between instances. But what i need to reset that value? I was thinking to call some API of all the instances and reset it everywhere. But i do not know the addresses of all the instances/node. That is why i am asking here.

Comment: Sounds like you need a distributed cache with an invalidation callback, not any of what you have currently.

Comment: Yes, right now it is implemented using caching to invalidate it. But the case is for each request we need to check that value in cache,

Comment: Hence, the invalidation callback. The key is that you invalidate the cache when the underlying data changes (through messaging, monitoring, etc.), not that you check everytime. That obviously would render the cache pointless.